# How to parallel process a function, with loops

Tags: bash, loops, parallel-processing, sh, gnu-parallel

So I have this function, I want this function to run everything that It contains in itself at the same time. So far it isn't working, and according to other sources, this is how you do it. The function itself works if its not in parallel.

```
#!/bin/bash
foo () {
    cd ${HOME}/sh/path/to/script/execute
    for f in *.sh; do  #goes to "execute" directory and executes all 
    #scripts the current directory "execute" basically run-parts without cron

        cd ~/sh/path/to/script
        while IFS= read -r l1 #Line 1 in master.txt
              IFS= read -r l2 #Line 2 in master.txt
              IFS= read -r l3 #Line 3 in master.txt
        do
        cd /dev/shm/arb
        echo ${l1} > arg.txt & echo ${l2} > arg2.txt & echo ${l3} > arg3.txt 
        cd ${HOME}/sh/path/to/script/execute 
        bash -H ${f} #executes all scripts inside "execute" folder
        cd ~/sh/path/to/script/here
        ./here.sh &
        cd ~/sh/path/to/script &
        done <master.txt
    done

}

export -f foo
parallel ::: foo
```

## Results in

```
#No result at all....., just buffers. htop doesn't acknowledge any 
#processes, and when this runs its pretty taxing on the cores.
```

## master.txt content

In case this is relevant:

```
apple_fruit
apple_veggie
veggie_fruit
#apple changes
pear_fruit
pear_veggie
veggie_fruit
#pear changes
cucumber_fruit
...
```

I'm very new to using parallel, and don't know how it works in advanced(and basic) situations so would the loops interfere? And if it does interfere, is there a workaround?

Comment: The idea of **GNU Parallel** is that you have lots of things to do, and you execute lots of instances of `foo()` in parallel. So, you need to aim for `parallel foo ::: <lots of things>`

Comment: What do you think `cd somewhere &` does? It starts a new process in the background, which then changes directory and exits... without affecting the foreground process.

Comment: that was a typo, I removed it

Comment: You can't have tens or hundreds of parallel tasks all writing at the same time to `arg[1-3].txt` - you'll make a mess!

Comment: Only thing that should be going in there is first three lines of ```master.txt```, it rewrites because its not getting appended.

Comment: When multiple `*.sh` are running at the same time, they are all going go write to the same `arg1.txt`...

Comment: so it puts anything outputed to the terminal into ```arg1.txt``` along with the echo. even though you need the ${f} variable to fetch that data?

Comment: Try commenting out everything in `foo()` and just having `echo $1` inside `foo()`. Then run `cd ${HOME}/sh/path/to/script/execute; parallel foo ::: *.sh`

Comment: Ok cool, so would this be possible to do this if you removed the loops. I saw another question who asked the same thing. Except it was a lot more simple function, it was solved with ```parallel ::: foo```

Comment: I can't really see what you are trying to do, you change directory very often and run scripts I can't see that do things I don't know. However, you can run a bunch of parallel jobs like you just did, each one processing one `.sh` file, so hopefully that will get you started.

Comment: It did, thanks for tirelessly correcting my amateurish attempts with GNU Parallel.

Comment: Glad it worked out :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The result is probably going to be something like:

```
inner() {
  script="$1"
  parallel -N3 "'$script' {}; here.sh  {}"  :::: master.txt
}
export -f inner
parallel inner ::: ${HOME}/sh/path/to/script/execute/*.sh
```

This will call each of the scripts in `${HOME}/sh/path/to/script/execute/` (and `here.sh`) with 3 arguments from `master.txt` like this:

```
${HOME}/sh/path/to/script/execute/script1.sh apple_fruit apple_veggie veggie_fruit
```

You need to change the scripts so that:

- They get the arguments from the command line (not from `arg.txt`, `arg2.txt`, `arg3.txt`).
- They send their output to stdout

Comment: Could parallel be referenced with $2, if you put ```parallel inner ::: ${HOME}/sh/path/to/script/execute/*.sh {insert command here to be referenced by $2}```

Comment: Here I moved that question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636075/parallel-how-to-reference-multiple-arguments-from-a-function