# Parallel: How to reference multiple arguments from a function

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, arguments, gnu-parallel

I have this function and I need it to reference multiple arguments from a function using GNU parallel.

```
foo () {

    cd ${HOME}/sh/xxx/xxx/xxx/folder_with_scripts
    bash -H $1 #replace with echo in test run {echo $1 is being echoed}
    bash -H $2 #replace with echo in test run {echo $2 is being echoed}
}

export -f foo
parallel foo ::: *script.sh bash*.sh
```

## folder_with_scripts content

```
$ ls
firstscript.sh
secondscript.sh
thirdscript.sh
bashhim.sh
bashscript.sh
bashher.sh
```

`parallel foo` basically executes all scripts following `*script.sh` inside by referencing it as an argument inside `foo`. Which is `$1`. What I'm trying to do is have it also execute `bash*.sh*` which are inside `folders_with_scripts`directory by using `$2`.

According to `man parallel`, the syntax is:

```
 parallel [options] [command [arguments]] ( ::: arguments | :::: argfile(s) )
```

Since `::: arguments` is plural, I'm assuming this is very possible.

## result

#### For convenience sake, I'm replacing `bash` with `echo`

```
$ ./foo.sh
firstscript.sh is being echoed
secondscript.sh is being echoed
thirdscript.sh is being echoed
              is being echoed
              is being echoed
              is being echoed
```

## wanted result

```
firstscript.sh is being echoed
secondscript.sh is being echoed
thirdscript.sh is being echoed
bashhim.sh is being echoed
bashscript.sh is being echoed
bashher.sh is being echoed
```

#### For my case, `parallel foo ::: *.sh` won't cut it.

#### Swapping the positions of `$1` with `*script.sh` won't cut it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to run all `bash*.sh` for each `*script.sh`:

```
parallel foo ::: *script.sh ::: bash*.sh
```

If each `bash*.sh` is linked to a `*script.sh` (`:::+` is introduced in version 20160422):

```
parallel foo ::: *script.sh :::+ bash*.sh
```

Test it with `--dry-run`:

```
parallel --dry-run foo ::: *script.sh ::: bash*.sh
parallel --dry-run foo ::: *script.sh :::+ bash*.sh
```

If this does not answer your question, please update the question with what commands you want GNU Parallel to run, e.g.:

```
foo firstscript.sh bashhim.sh
foo secondscript.sh thirdscript.sh
foo bashscript.sh bashher.sh
```

and show the output of `echo *script.sh bash*.sh` in the dir where you run `parallel`.

The data behind `:::` is called an input source.
Dealing with input sources is covered in chapter 4 of https://zenodo.org/record/1146014 (Printed: http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html)